# Number of home directories in children of /

Tags: grep, directory, pipe, home

I have to count the number of children directories of / that contain one or more home directories.
For instance, if john, emily and rick have their home directories in /home/john , /home/emily and /var/lib, the answer would be 2.

I assume I have to use a pipe with cut and grep, but I do not know exactly how.

Comment: I don't understand how /var/lib is different from /home/john or /home/emily in this regard. None of them are *direct* children of `/`; two of them contain `/home`, if that's what you're checking...?

Comment: Is the algorithm that "/home" contains two homedirs and /var contains one, so there are two unique top-level directories that contain home directories?

Comment: Are the paths to test predetermined or are you reading them from the `/etc/passwd` file?  And would *3* the answer to this list: `/home/john , /home/emily , /varlib , /home/sally/Documents/Earth , /var/www ` ?

Comment: You only need to find out where the home directory is set which you can get from `getent passwd | awk - F : '{print $6}'`. It is most likely `/home` for everyone unless it's been set as a different location for some of the users. Assuming that it is, you can use `find /home -maxdepth 1 -type d | awk 'END {print $NR}'` and that will give you the total number. You can swap out `/home` if it's elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
(export LC_ALL=C
getent passwd | cut -d: -f6 | sort -t/ -uk2,2 | grep -c ..)
```

Counts the number of unique second components of user's home directories.

- `LC_ALL=C` generally needed when we use `uniq` or `sort -u`
- `getent passwd` returns the account database (assuming it can be enumerated which is not always the case for networked ones) as a csv (colon separated)
- `cut -d: -f6` extracts the 6th field of each record (the home directory)
- `sort -t/ -uk2,2` sorts on the second directory component and with `-u` retains only one record for each unique sorting key
- `grep -c ..` count the number of lines containing at least two characters, to exclude `/` (alternatively: `grep -cvx /`)

The `cut` + `sort` + `grep` could be replaced with one call to `awk`:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{split($6, p, "/")}
                         p[2] != "" && !seen[p[2]]++ {n++}
                         END {print n}'
```